# MySQL error when importing database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql

I installed a script and am supposed to import a database file, but when i import i get this error

Error
SQL query:

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `framework`
--
-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `feedback`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `feedback` (

 `ID` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `userid` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `email` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `message` TEXT NOT NULL ,
 `title` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `timestamp` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `ID` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1046 - No database selected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the database name in query or use the command:

```
use `framework`;
```

write the above line at the starting of the query. Or you can use the

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `framework`.`feedback` (
                             ^^ your database name
```

database name in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Put database name in front of table name in your `CREATE` query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  database_name.`feedback` (    <---
```

In other way you can select the database before inserting your query:

```
USE database_name;
```

In your case, I guess database name is `framework`

Comment: i added the framework, but still same error, or does it mean i have to change the database name in mysql to framework. because the instruction on the script says i create any database name and input values in config.php file